# How to render a checked checkbox using knockout js when page is loaded

Tags: knockout.js

I've just started playing around with Knockout.js, and it seems really cool. What I have is a table. I am displaying 10 rows in this table with the first column being checkbox. When the page is loaded i want to render the page so that first checkbox is checked by default. My code so far is as below.

```
               <tbody data-bind="foreach: ExistingTablesInfo">
                <tr>
                    <td class="input-group">
                        <input type="checkbox" />
                    </td>
                    <td data-bind="text: aaa"></td>
                    <td data-bind="text: bbb"></td>
                    <td data-bind="text: ccc"></td>
                    <td data-bind="text: moment(ddd).format('L')"></td>
                    <td data-bind="text: moment(eee).format('L')"></td>
                    <td data-bind="text: moment(fff).format('L')"></td>
                    <td data-bind="text: ggg"></td>
                    <td data-bind="text: hhh"></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to have an observable variable in ExistingTablesInfo array. If you have existing data you can add one extra parameter using `map()` but at last structure should look like below.
Also use `checked` binding to bind that observable, set it to true to checked and false to unchecked. Its 2 ways binding so values of property will change if you change check box state.

```js
function viewModel() {
  var self = this;
  
  self.ExistingTablesInfo = ko.observableArray([
      {isSelected : ko.observable(true), aaa:"aaa1", bbb:"bbb", ccc:"ccc"},
      {isSelected : ko.observable(true), aaa:"aaa2", bbb:"bbb", ccc:"ccc"},
      {isSelected : ko.observable(true), aaa:"aaa3", bbb:"bbb", ccc:"ccc"},
      {isSelected : ko.observable(false), aaa:"aaa4", bbb:"bbb", ccc:"ccc"},
      {isSelected : ko.observable(true), aaa:"aaa5", bbb:"bbb", ccc:"ccc"},
      {isSelected : ko.observable(true), aaa:"aaa6", bbb:"bbb", ccc:"ccc"}
   ])
}

ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>col1</th>
    <th>col2</th>
    <th>col3</th>
    <th>col4</th>
  </tr>
  <tbody data-bind="foreach: ExistingTablesInfo">
    <tr>
      <td class="input-group">
        <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked:isSelected" />
      </td>
      <td data-bind="text: aaa"></td>
      <td data-bind="text: bbb"></td>
      <td data-bind="text: ccc"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>

</table>
```